# Kotlin - Unable to parse JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, kotlin

I am trying to parse a JSON using Kotlin (I'm new to Kotlin / Android) and I can't seem to find a way to get it done.

```
[{
    "submission_date": "March 2018",
    "user_answers": [{
        "question_id": 0,
        "answer": 5
    }, {
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer": 5
    }]
}, {
    "submission_date": "March 2018",
    "user_answers": [{
        "question_id": 0,
        "answer": 0
    }, {
        "question_id": 1,
        "answer": 0
    }]
}]
```

After trying for some time with Klaxon I decided to give GSON a try and start following this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53BsyxwSBJk

The code seems pretty straight forward:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val userSessions = gson.fromJson(userDataJSON, UserSession::class.java)
```

Here are the models:

```
class UserSession(submissionDate : String)
{
    var submissionDate : String
    var userAnswers : ArrayList<UserAnswer> = ArrayList<UserAnswer>()

    init
    {
        this.submissionDate = submissionDate
    }

    // We call this function later on, when we have a UserAnswer array  to work with
    fun addArray(userAnswersArray : ArrayList<UserAnswer>)
    {
        if(userAnswersArray.size > 0)
        {
            for (userAnswer : UserAnswer in userAnswersArray)
            {
                this.userAnswers.add(userAnswer)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println("No user answer found. Array is empty.")
        }
    }
}

class UserAnswer(idQuestion : Int, userAnswer : Int)
{
    var idQuestion : Int
    var userAnswer : Int

    init
    {
        this.idQuestion = idQuestion
        this.userAnswer = userAnswer
    }
}
```

However, I get `JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $`
As far as I'm aware, the JSON is valid, or so JSONLint says.

Any ideas? I've been struggling for some time with parsing this JSON without any luck.

Comment: try using   `Array<UserSession>::class.java!!`  instead of `UserSession::class.java`

Comment: Thanks. It was the first thing I tried before posting here but it didn't work.  I renamed the variables and changed to ArrayList and it worked.

Comment: Try JSON2Kotlin, you might want to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n46WbgNoEnE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is problem with variable name as you are going to map your json directly into pojo (model) class with gson. always json key name and model variable name should be same while working with gson.

changes should like this :

- json should be same as showing
- change variable type in models :

  var submission_date : String

  var user_answers : ArrayList = ArrayList()

  var question_id : Int

  var answer : Int

change all getter / setter and methods according to these variable name

this will works..

Answer (score 3):

> JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

This exception is raised when **Gson attempts to read (or write) a malformed JSON element**.You should Rectify your **MODEL** class

**`val user_answers:ArrayList<User_answers>`**

Try this way,

```
class YOUR_MODEL_CLASS( val submission_date:String, val user_answers:ArrayList<User_answers>)
data class User_answers
(
    val question_id   : Int,
    val answer        : Int

)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped.

Comment: @daydr3am3r Move ahead!